# C#: How to replace \\ with \

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, escaping

I have this string temp and I want to replace `\\` with `\`

```
string temp = "\\h\\k";
```

I've tried doing `temp.Replace("\\", "\")` however the output is `hk`
I want the output to be `\h\k`

How to replace `"\\"` with `"\"`?

Thank you

Comment: Does temp.Replace("\\", "\") compile? Wouldn't it complain that "\" is a bad compile constant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the question isn't quite clear, are you looking for this?

```
string temp = @"\\h\\k";
temp = temp.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Comment: No need to add @ everywhere.

    string temp = "\\h\\k";
    temp.Replace("\\",@"\");

Comment: @manojlds: No. the two parameters of the Replace method in your example are now exactly the same. `"\\"` is the same as `@"\"`

Comment: It gives the expected output though. Trying to figure out what is happening however. Maybe, when we say temp.Replace("\\",@"\"), temp itself becomes @"\h\k" and it replaces "\" with "\" and we get the output of "\h\k" ?

Comment: Indeed you start out with a wrong string `"\\h\\k"` actually is  `@"\h\k"` So in your example you are replacing the single slashes with single slashes...

Comment: @sarsnake - While debugging you'll see temp change in the 'locals' view from "\\\\h\\\\k" to "\\h\\k". It does work.

Answer (score 7):

```
temp.Replace("\\\\", "\\")
```

That should work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the slashes each time:

```
temp.Replace("\\\\", "\\")
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
string temp = "\\h\\k";
temp = temp.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
```